# What is the antonym for the word 'kafir' in Urdu?

Tags: terminology, kuffar

I want to know the appropriate word for antonym/opposite for 'Kafir'

Comment: Mu`min .........

Answer (score 4):

مؤمن (Mu`min) is the antonym for (Kaafir) كافر. it means believer, whereas kaafir means non-believer.

kaafir  has another meaning which is ungrateful. In such a case, the antonym would be شاكر (shakir) - which means grateful.

Comment: I'm not able to read the Urdu text. Would you please spell the words in English also?

Answer (score 1):

Whereas Urdu could be considered as a language which has many similarities to Arabic, especially in Fiqh, as a result, it could be declared that:

**The word believer or (Mo'men)مومن can be selected as the most adequate equivalent for the antonym of Kafir.**

It can be surveyed from this another aspect that: whereas the word Kafir almost means unbeliever in English, then its antonym could be termed as the word "Believer" which means: **مومن** (based on my common knowledge).